# Django S3 uploaded file urls show credentials

Tags: python, django, url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `django-storages` and Amazon S3 for file storages. In my model I have:
`avatar = models.ImageField(_('Avatar'), upload_to='avatars/profiles/', blank=True, null=True)`

The image is uploaded successfully on `save`, but full url with credentials is saved. In my Retrieve requests/ when I read the url from db via console) I get  something like:
https://subdomain.amazonaws.com/avatars/profiles/filename.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=XXX&X-Amz-Expires=XXX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=XXXX&X-Amz-Signature=XXXX&X-Amz-Date=XXXXXX&X-Amz-Credential=XXXX

How can I prevent this? I could strip the url before responding, but I do not need and therefore do not want to save them in this format, because all files can be accessed publicly, also no need for credentials.
Ps. I though of using the `post_save` hook but it seemed like a hack to me.

Answer (score 9):

To remove the authentication credentials in the query string, set `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` in your `settings.py`. From `django-storages` documentation at https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html:

> `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` (optional; default is `True`)
>
> Setting `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH` to `False` to remove query parameter authentication from generated URLs. This can be useful if your S3 buckets are public.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in `X-Amz-Credentials` is your access key. In Amazon context it is not considered sensitive information, so it can be stored in plain text.

Comment: But the image links work exactly the same without the parameters, so I do not want to store them at all, or send them as responses to queries. For the sake of clarity/simplicity, even if it makes no other difference.

Answer (score 0):

if you set `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` in `settings.py`,
django-storages will return custom-doamin without query string

you can reference below piece of code of class S3BotoStorage

```
def url(self, name, headers=None, response_headers=None, expire=None):
    # Preserve the trailing slash after normalizing the path.
    name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
    if self.custom_domain:
        return "%s//%s/%s" % (self.url_protocol,
                              self.custom_domain, filepath_to_uri(name))

    if expire is None:
        expire = self.querystring_expire

    return self.connection.generate_url(
        expire,
        method='GET',
        bucket=self.bucket.name,
        key=self._encode_name(name),
        headers=headers,
        query_auth=self.querystring_auth,
        force_http=not self.secure_urls,
        response_headers=response_headers,
    )
```